# Creating a second domain in a forest using install-addsdomain

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, powershell-v3.0

I have a domain ludwig.example.com and am trying to create a domain amadeus.example.com using install-addsdomain.

I am running this command:

```
install-addsdomain -newdomainname amadeus.example.com -parentdomainname ludwig.example.com -domaintype treedomain
```

I am running this as a local administrator and was a bit surprised I didn't get any errors regarding access denied on the ludwig domain I thought the command would have to contact.

In fact the command just tells me that there are a few DNS-related warnings and never terminates. The server remains outside any domains.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `-Credential (Get-Credential CORP\EnterpriseAdmin)` to supply the parent domain enterprise administrator credentials before the 
`-newdomainname amadeus.example.com -parentdomainname ludwig.example.com -domaintype treedomain`

Here is the full example from Microsoft:

```
C:\PS>Install-ADDSDomain -Credential (Get-Credential CORP\EnterpriseAdmin1) -NewDomainName child -ParentDomainName corp.contoso.com -InstallDNS -CreateDNSDelegation -DomainMode Win2003 -ReplicationSourceDC DC1.corp.contoso.com -SiteName Houston -DatabasePath "D:\NTDS" -SYSVOLPath "D:\SYSVOL" -LogPath "E:\Logs" -NoRebootOnCompletion
```

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974722%28v=wps.620%29.aspx)

Comment: I was wondering why the command ran away without wondering why it didn't have the credentials it needed.